# How to define a custom layout of view.phml used by product review on selected categories

Tags: layout, review

I was able to define a view.phtml custom layout on selected categories by adding this entry to the category's '**Custom Layout Update:**' and set '**Apply to Products:**' to YES. My purpose was to hide the price/add to cart and replace with some image/text on selected categories.

```
<reference name="product.info">
         <action method="setTemplate">
<template>catalog/product/custom_view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

This works well except that when I clicked on review this product, it showed the default format with the price on it. I wanted to add an entry to set custom layout to REVIEW page as well.

[image: This is how the customized layout looks like:]

[image: This is the review page]

Comment: Well, still waiting for experts who can help me out. This is really a big deal to the project since the client is selling important plane parts.

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue why this happens, if you have a look on `\Mage_Review_ProductController::listAction` it looks like the custom design  is applied:

```
if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
    $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
}
```

Therefore should you make sure, that the name of the block in your `review.xml` is still correct `<block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">`

No other idea except just digging into and using xdebug a lot!